# Wordpress how to move the footer down

Tags: wordpress, footer, move, put

I have [a site on WordPress](http://www.salonestella.it) that is showing the footer at the end of the content instead at the bottom of the page (when there isn't enough content on the page in order to fill it).
This issues is showing either when I'm browsing the site with lower screen resolutions.
I have this problem also in all my other Wordpress websites.
How could I solve this without causing a mess on the CSS?

Comment: Please post HTML and CSS code so we can better help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is typical behavior.  So I guess what you want is an overlay that's at a fixed position to the screen and does not scroll with the page.  Is that correct?

Checkout this [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-make-footer-fixed-to-the-bottom-of-the-screen/) it might be just what you want.  Personally, I would find it to be a nuisance on a my laptop because all of your pages are larger than my screen and I presume that the footer would now cover up more of the page.  But it's your website and it's your choice.  Have fun with it.